# Ĉu "nek ... nek" estas deviga en tiu ĉi frazo?

Tags: grammar

Ĉu en tiu ĉi frazo

```
Kaj ŝi kaj li ne emis veni.
```

oni **nepre** devas uzi `nek ... nek`?

```
Nek ŝi nek li emis veni.
```

La frazo okazis dum normala ĉiutaga interparolado. En la momento aŭdeblis strangete sed eble ĝi tamen gramatike ĝustas.

Se parolanto *malfrue* rimarkas ke la dua parto estas negativa, estus tro peze rediri la tutan subjekton kun la sama emfazo, uzante `nek ... nek`. Tio okazis ĉi foje, mi pensas.

Comment: Vi pravas en ambaŭ punktoj. En parolo estus tro peze rediri, sed en la teksto oni korektu, ĉar _kaj… kaj… ne…_ sonas strange.

Answer (score 1):

Estas diversaj eblecoj envortigi saman sencon.

- Kaj ŝi kaj li ne emis veni.
- Nek li nek ŝi emis veni.
- Ambaŭ li kaj ŝi ne emis veni.

Ktp. Ja Esperanto estas tre fleksebla lingvo!